# laravel eloquen relation not working on debian apache2 php5 server

Tags: laravel, server, eloquent, debian

i have develop a Laravel 5.2 application on my local windows10 PC using xampp with apache2 and php 7.0.3 as environment and everything works fine. i also have try it on xampp with php 5.3 installed, it run well. Now i would like to deploy the apps on debian 8 jessie server with apache2 and php 5.6 installed.

After i uploaded the apps, i got a problem every time i refer to a eloquent relation like in the code below

```
@if ($pegawai->list_pendidikan_pegawai->count() >0)
   @foreach ($pegawai->list_pendidikan_pegawai as $pendidikan) 
      @if (($pendidikan->pendidikan_pendidikan != null) && ($pendidikan->status != 0)) 
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
          <td>{{$pendidikan->pendidikan_pendidikan->nama}}</td>
          <td>{{$pendidikan->nama_tempat}}</td>
          <td>{{$pendidikan->no_ijazah}}</td>
          <td>{{$pendidikan->tgl_ijazah->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
        </tr>
       @else
       @endif
     @endforeach
 @endif
```

it returns

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

based ont the example above, here is the riwayat_pendidikan model

```
class riwayat_pendidikan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'riwayat_pendidikan';

    protected $fillable = ['pegawai', 'jenjang_pendidikan', 'pendidikan', 'nama_tempat', 'propinsi', 'kabkot', 'tempat', 'no_ijazah', 'tgl_ijazah', 'kepala', 'scan_ijazah', 'status'];

    public function pendidikan_pendidikan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ref_jenis_pendidikan', 'pendidikan', 'id');
    }

}
```

and here is the master model

```
class master extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'master';

    protected $fillable = ['pegawai', 'sk_pengangkatan', 'tmt_pengangkatan', 'pendidikan', 'jabatan', 'jenis_kepegawaian', 'unor', 'unor_induk', 'scan_izin_prinsip', 'pejabat_pengangkat','status'];

    public function list_pendidikan_pegawai()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\riwayat_pendidikan', 'pegawai', 'id');
    }

}
```

Here is is the controller

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $pegawai = master::find($id);
        return view('show.show_pegawai', compact('pegawai'));
}
```

here is the php --ini result on that debian server

```
/root$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
```

I have no idea why it got an error on different environment. Any help you can throw my way would be great. I'm very stuck with this.

Here is the dd($pegawai) result

```
master {#407 ▼
  #table: "master"
  #fillable: array:11 [▶]
  #dates: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:15 [▶]
  #original: array:15 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "pegawai" => 2
    "pendidikan" => 0
    "sk_pengangkatan" => "123644747hhhh"
    "tmt_pengangkatan" => "2016-06-01"
    "jabatan" => 27
    "jenis_kepegawaian" => 3
    "unor" => 992
    "unor_induk" => 28
    "pejabat_pengangkat" => ""
    "scan_izin_prinsip" => ""
    "status" => 1
    "deleted_at" => "2016-06-12 20:54:53"
    "created_at" => "2016-06-07 07:19:04"
    "updated_at" => "2016-06-12 13:54:53"
  ]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

Comment: can you add the result from dd($pegawai) in the controller? Is it null?

Comment: Did you give right permission to storage folder?

Comment: @IshaS i have done the chmod -R 0777 to the folder.

Comment: run composer dumpautoload and see

Comment: Also look at minimum server requirement of the document https://laravel.com/docs/5.2